# How to add reaction and source terms to a diffusion PDE solver written with MATLAB's pdepe function?

Tags: pde, matlab, finite-difference, parabolic-pde, implicit-methods

I have the following system of equations which I'm trying to solve using Matlab's `pdepe` solver.

The 1-D spherical heat diffusion equation with heat generation (source term):

$$
\rho \, C_p\frac{\partial T}{\partial t} = 
\frac{1}{r^2} \frac{\partial}{\partial r} \left(r^2 \, k \frac{\partial T}{\partial r} \right) + \Delta H \frac{\partial \rho_w}{\partial t} \\
$$

and boundary conditions:

$$
k \frac{\partial T}{\partial r} = h\,(T_\infty - T_s) \; \; \text{at r = surface}\\
\frac{\partial T}{\partial r} = 0 \; \; \text{at r = 0}
$$

also note that $\Delta H$ is a constant, i.e. $\Delta H = -255,000$. The initial value for $\rho_w = \rho_{initial} = 700$ and the ambient temperature $T_\infty = 773$ (see Matlab code below for more details).

The kinetic reactions of the system:

$$
\frac{\partial \rho_w}{\partial t} = -(K_1+K_2+K_3) \rho_w \\
\frac{\partial \rho_g}{\partial t} = K_1 \rho_w \\
\frac{\partial \rho_T}{\partial t} = K_2 \rho_w \\
\frac{\partial \rho_c}{\partial t} = K_3 \rho_w \\
\frac{\partial \rho_g}{\partial t} = K_4 \rho_T \\
\frac{\partial \rho_c}{\partial t} = K_5 \rho_T \\
\text{where}\; \; K = A\,e^{\frac{-E}{RT}}
$$

The thermal parameters $\rho, C_p, k$ vary according to the following:

$$
\rho = \rho_w + \rho_c \\
Y_w = \frac{\rho_w}{\rho_{initial}} \\
C_p = Y_w C_{pw} + (1-Y_w) C_{pc} \\
k = Y_w k_w + (1-Y_w) k_c 
$$

where $C_{pw} = 1500$, $C_{pc} = 1100$, $k_w = 0.105$, and $k_c = 0.071$.

I can solve the single PDE for heat diffusion (no source term) using the `pdepe` function in Matlab as follows:

```
function PDEexampleSphere

d350 = 0.035e-2; % diameter
r350 = d350/2;   % radius
Ti = 300;
Tinf = 773;
tmax = 0.8;

m = 2;
x = linspace(0,r350,20);
t = 0:0.01:tmax;

sol = pdepe(m,@pdefunc,@icfunc,@bcfunc,x,t);
u = sol;

% surface plot
figure(3)
surf(x,t,u) 
xlabel('Distance (m)')
ylabel('Time (s)')

% temperature profile
figure(4)
plot(t,u(:,1),'b',t,u(:,end),'r')
hold on
plot([0 tmax],[Tinf Tinf],':k')
hold off
axis([0 tmax Ti-20 Tinf+20])
xlabel('Time (s)')
ylabel('Temperature (K)')

% --------------------------------------------------------------
function [c,f,s] = pdefunc(x,t,u,dudx)
rho = 700;  % density
cp = 1500;  % heat capacity
k = 0.105;  % thermal conductivity

c = rho*cp;
f = k.*dudx;
s = 0;

% --------------------------------------------------------------
function u0 = icfunc(x)
Ti = 300;   % initial temperature

u0 = Ti;

% --------------------------------------------------------------
function [pl,ql,pr,qr] = bcfunc(xl,ul,xr,ur,t)
h = 375;    % heat transfer coefficient
Tinf = 773; % ambient temperature

pl = 0;
ql = 0;
pr = -h*(Tinf-ur);
qr = 1;
```

How can I include the kinetic reactions and heat generation term into the Matlab function?

Note - for more information on the `pdepe` function in Matlab, please see the following documentation: http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/pdepe.html

Comment: This might be relevant... http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ri_1nxwupb8

Comment: @boyfarrell The video demonstrates exactly what I did in the above Matlab code for a single PDE and no source term. While helpful, it does not answer my question.

Comment: What do the docs say about adding a source term? Can't you literally just add a source term to your equation, is there something preventing you from doing that?

Comment: @boyfarrell The documentation states $s(x,t,u,\frac{\partial u}{\partial x})$ but my source term is in terms of $\rho$ not temperature.

Comment: Does the `pdepe` solver accept coupled PDEs? If so you could solve the first equation for $\frac{\partial T}{\partial t}$ and the second for $\frac{\partial u}{\partial t}$? You could simply use the solution of the second equation as the source term to the first. Provided you have initial conditions (so you know $s(t=0)$) it should be possible to include the value numerically in this way. Sorry I'm not really at MATLAB person, these are the things I would try.

Comment: @boyfarrell The `pdepe` solver accepts a system of PDEs. See the link I posted at the end of the question for more info.

Comment: @boyfarrell Please note that I edited the heat equation. I forgot to include the $\frac{\partial}{\partial r}$ term.

Comment: I'm facing the same problem. I already tried to solve all the equation together, ode's and the pde, but matlab keep saying that: "Error using pdepe (line 293)
Spatial discretization has failed.
Discretization supports only parabolic and
elliptic equations, with flux term involving
spatial derivative." I already tried also solve the odes separately, but it didn't work out because of the strange time step made by the function pdepe. I'm trying to change the function pdepe, but if you could help me, it would be great!

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](http://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](http://scicomp.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough [reputation](http://scicomp.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation).

Comment: Yes, it indeed does not answer the question, but I thought maybe M Gavin has already solved his problem and I could ask him, since I'm facing the same problem.

Comment: @FathiAlexandre I quit using Matlab and have transitioned completely to Python. And yes, I have it working in Python.

Comment: @Gavin I tried to add a comment in the answer where you replied me, but I don't have reputation enough. So I'm thinking about change my model to python as well, could you fill me with some of your codes, so I could start learning about and see how you managed to solve the problem? Thanks anyway for answering me!

Comment: @FathiAlexandre My contact information can be found on my profile page. Send me an email about your question and I'll try to help. Or you can post your question on this Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 2):

Since `pdepe` accepts systems of PDEs through vector-valued capacity, flux, and source terms, one way to accommodate your request would be to set the fluxes for all of the $\rho$ variables equal to zero. The capacity terms for the $\rho$ variables will all be 1, and the source terms for each variable are the non-flux terms on the right-hand side (the $\rho$ variables have no flux terms, so for these variables, the source term is also the *only* term on the right-hand side of these equations). Without knowing more about the methods used by `pdepe`, it's difficult to say whether or not this kludge will be numerically stable, but my guess is that it would probably work.

Comment: Can you provide some Matlab code demonstrating this?

Comment: Actually, some Python code demonstrating this would be better.